# Scatter Plot with Conditions

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Suppose I have a data frame

```
name = ['A', 'B', 'C'] 
score = [2,4,6]
```

I want to create a scatter plot with the following conditions, color the bubble as green if the score is greater than 3 and red otherwise. I'd also like to label the bubble with its respective name.

I'm only able to create a scatter plot with the bubble having the respective name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of scatter plot is best performed in [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) for Python.

```
# example from: https://python-graph-gallery.com/?s=scatter
# library & dataset
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('iris')

# Use the 'hue' argument to provide a factor variable
sns.lmplot( x="sepal_length", y="sepal_width", data=df, fit_reg=False, hue='species', legend=False)

# Move the legend to an empty part of the plot
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
```

The keyword `hue` will designate which variable is the one which is used for labeling the data points. Also, have a look at the link provided for more examples.